# Set multi-dimensional array through function parameters

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm working on a simple session manager for my framework. Im trying to setup a more user friendly structure for the session data. Essentially my sessions are stored like this:

```
 $app_name = "Some_App_Name";
 $component = "notifications";
 $key = "errors";
 $value = "There was some error";
 $_SESSION[$app_name][$component][$key] = $value;
```

The problem I am facing is creating this structure through parameters within the session class. I have a set method which should ideally set a session value. The $app_name as listed above is by default added to the session class through the constructor, but I need to find a simple way of taking the parameters passed in within the method and then creating the rest. A simple example:

```
// Where keys could be: $key1 = notifications, $key2 => "notices"
public static function set($key1,$key2,$value) {
    $_SESSION[self::$app_name][$key1][$key2] = $value;
}
```

The above would work if I always have 4 parameters but in some cases I might only have 2 parameters. I could pass 2 parameters (both being an array) but I'm looking for a more streamlined approach (if such an approach exists).

With the creating of the structure and setting values I also need a similiar way of verifying if the value or last key exists:

```
// Where keys could be: $key1 = notifications, $key2 => "errors"
public static function exists($key1,$key2) {
    if(isset($_SESSION[self::$app_name][$key1][$key2])) {
    return true;
}
```

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the light of assisting other members wanting to do something similiar, I want to strongly advise you against using this concept as off the bat it sounds like a good idea but your true issue comes with the management of the array itself. Working straight with the $_SESSION superglobal really is the more powerful option on the basis that:

- Even with a parameter in place for say server and component ($_SESSION ['somename']['auth']), what happens when you want to access content from that level from another instance of the object? Say I have another session object instance for $_SESSION ['somename']['errors'] but need to access properties from $_SESSION ['somename']['auth'] but within scope my base within the session array is incorrect.
- Adding properties is fine $this->session->add("key","name") but what if you want to append to that array (where name is actually an array and not just a value), or vise versa. Or checking for occurances if $_SESSION['somename']['auth']['key']['name'] actually has another key or value within it?

All and all having worked with this the last couple of days I can definately say that it might not be impossible to write a "fully functional" session manager class but at the end of the day for simplicity it's better to rather just work with the session array directly as it's less code and less issues as you go.

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = array(
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2",
    "value" => "value"
);

public static function set($params = NULL)  //default null if no value is passed
{
    if (!self::exists($params)) return false;

    $_SESSION[self::$app_name][$params["key1"]][$params["key2"]] = $value;
    return true;        

} 


public static function exists($params = NULL) 
{
    if(isset($_SESSION[self::$app_name][$params["key1"]][$params["key2"]])) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm not always sure how many parameters there may be. I want to create the function to utilise all of the passed parameters (could be anything from 1 - 1000 haha) and create the structure and take the last parameter as the value.